# Excel MDX linked server fails connection test

Tags: sql-server, excel, mdx, linked-server, connectivity

My first post after 2 years of learning to write SQL and using SQL Server, most of my questions have been answered researching on this website, however I cannot find the answer to my question below:

I am creating a new linked server, grabbing data from Excel using an MDX query in my SQL script. For example:

```
SELECT *   
into raw.example
FROM openquery( Test1, 'MDX CODE/etc etc'
```

I clicked on my database > Server Objects > Linked Servers > New Linked Server >

```
Linker Server: TESTEXAMPLE
Server Type: other data source
Provider: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Analysis Services 10.0
Product Name: Test1
Data Source: Name of server
Provider String: 
Location:
Catalog: OLAP
```

After I click "ok" to create this linked server this message comes up:

> The linked server has been created but failed a connection test. Do you want to keep the linked server?
>
> OLE DB provider 'MSOLAP' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7308)

I am not sure why it isn't connecting. Is it a server issue where I have to ask for permission to access it? Or do I somehow need to revert away from the provider being configured to run in a single-threaded apartment mode?

I am doing this on my local SQL Server Express Edition machine. Whereas before my script and `OPENQUERY/MDX` query worked on a remote desktop server etc.

I have looked at other posts but those solutions do not solve my problem.

Comment: do any of these help?: https://www.google.com/search?q=OLE+DB+provider+%27MSOLAP%27+cannot+be+used+for+distributed+queries+because+the+provider+is+configured+to+run+in+single-threaded+apartment+mode.+%28Microsoft+SQL+Server%2C+Error%3A+7308%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab

Comment: I have come across that link when searching for answers. Thought it would help me create the linked server, but the error message still comes up. Thanks for this though.